# IIR filter SOS and Direct Forms doubt

Tags: matlab, filters, transfer-function, software-implementation, z-transform

I have below doubts, so confusing! As I don't want to assume from what I read, I am asking for help here!

**Are Second Order Sections another name for biQuads ?**

---

If I have 2 single pole transfer functions, then cascading them equals multiplying the polynomial; such as below?

$$H_1 =\frac{b_{10}+b_{11}Z^{-1}}{1-a_{10} Z^{-1}}$$ and $$H_2 =\frac{b_{20}+b_{21}Z^{-1}}{1-a_{20} Z^{-1}}$$

Then cascaded version is a 2nd order polynomial such as:

$$H_c =\frac{b_{0}+b_{1}Z^{-1}+b_{2}Z^{-2}}{1-a_{0} Z^{-1}-a_{1} Z^{-2}}$$ where **the poles and zeros can be obtained by taking root of this polynomial, which is not the two individual poles or zeros exist before cascading! Am I right?** Or taking square root will give the same poles or zeros of the individual ?

---

What is the mathematical steps behind the MATLAB commands `tf2zp` and `zp2sos`? How to do the same manually [just like we handcode calculation of the FFT using the butterfly tree diagram]?

---

[This](http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/curset/CMSIS/Documentation/DSP/html/group___biquad_cascade_d_f2_t.html) shows the `Direct form II Transposed structure` and it's implementation equation. Now taking values of $a_0$, $a_1$, $b_0$,$b_1$,$b_2$ from $H_c$ and using them in the implementation equation **is right**?

Comment: 2nd order sections are any section that contains a second order term (e.g.  a_{1} Z^{-2}).  A bi-quad is a specific representation or type of 2nd order section that includes all possible terms up to 2nd order in the numerator and denominator of the transfer function.  So a bi-quad is a specific representation of a second order section.

Comment: A biquad will generally have complex poles.  A bilinear section will not have complex poles if it is realizable.  So although you can multiply bilinear sections and produce a biquad, the two kinds of sections are used differently.  For example you would't get a particularly useful biquad by cascading two bilinear sections.

Comment: > biquad will generally hav complex poles!   So real pole biquads do exist?

Comment: Sure.  Take two bilinear expressions and multiply them together.  I don't know that biquads with real roots are particularly useful.  This topic usually comes up in the context of filter design.  Is that what you are working on?

Comment: i have a  series of 6 cascaded single pole filters, in matlab output is as expected, but when i am trying c implementation, it doesn't. I am pretty new in filter implementation, and is what i wanna learn